# Explain this C++ operator definition

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following operator defined in a C++ class called `StringProxy`:

```
operator std::string&()
{
    return m_string;
}
```

a) What is this and how does this work? I understand the idea of operator overloading, but they normally look like `X operator+(double i)`.

b) Given an instance of `StringProxy`, how can I use this operator to get the `m_string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conversion method.  To get the m_string, simply use an explicit cast: `(std::string)stringProxy` to perform the conversion.  Depending on context (e.g. if you're assigning to a string), you may be able to do without the cast.

Comment: I believe in general the C++ static_cast would be preferable to the old style C cast.

Comment: @Steven:  Not everyone agrees.  http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=285

Comment: IMO that article is largely based on a premise that when people program in C, they are all gurus, whereas C++ programmers are untrainable noobs. The C-style cast does not automatically do the *right* thing, it will do *some* thing, more often than not a reinterpret cast. One still needs to know what exactly it does in each case to know if it does the desired thing. - And there is one place where you absolutely need type-safe alternatives to C's corresponding non-typesafe functionality: *templates*.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cast operator. They take the form of operator T() and enable casting between custom types. You can get the std::string out by simply assigning it to a regular string or reference.